# Are all members of the United Federation of Planets on actual planets?

Tags: star-trek

It's called the "United Federation ***of Planets***".  But can a society located on something other than a planet (e.g. moon, asteroid, space station) become a member?

By "member", I mean that it is directly called such, or it has representatives in the [Federation Legislature](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/United_Federation_of_Planets#The_legislature).  Societies that are merely colonies or protectorates don't count (but [may later become members](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/214994/102339)).

Planets may not be fully settled, or have factions that aren't part of the Federation.  For the purpose of this question, they're still considered to be "on a planet" and therefore don't count.

Canonical sources (TV shows and movies) only, please.  Memory Alpha is not canon, and their [list of Federation members](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Federation_members) appears at first glance to be all planets anyway.

Comment: Except Earth's Moon?

Comment: To be fair to trek canon it is not clear who gets to be a member.  For example given Earth surely had colonies on the Moon, Mars, and Alpha Centauri prior to WWIII are all human colonies merely one member?   Early trek literature would imply Alpha Centauri is an independent member.   But that same literature would also give it a far more exotic backstory.   Likewise Vulcan surely had colonies during its aggressive expansion era that stayed unified with Vulcan unlike the lost Romulan tribe.  Maquis colonies obviously wanted out.

Comment: @Valorum: If the TV series or movies call Luna a member, sure.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Technically [Andoria](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Andoria) is a [moon](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Moon) of a gas giant in ST:Enterprise canon (like Endor is for Star Wars)

[image]

(I loathe Enterprise so answering this violated my headcanon)

Comment: Having seen STD and ST:Picard makes me yearn for the halcyon days of ST:Enteprise.